# Spacing in attribute table of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-pro

For some reason when I import data from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro, some of the data got messed up. For example; In ArcMap a column has "Concrete Foundation" ....but once imported into Pro, it ends up saying "ConcreteFoundation" and so on. I really need to learn Python apparently...but how can I fix this spacing error at the moment since I don't necessarily have the time to be studying Python at work.

Comment: Have you contacted ESRI about this? This would seem to be a pretty serious bug.

Comment: I have not...I don't seem to have the time. Super tight deadline coming up! Plus I am not sure how to contact them :P

Comment: Your best bet to fix this quickly is probably not to add back the deleted spaces. I'd try joining your old, correct attribute table to the new one and using the field calculator to overwrite the incorrect values.

Comment: How precisely did you "import data from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro"?

Comment: @PolyGeo , I go to the "Insert" tab and then I insert map, (from ArcMap).

Comment: Do you mean that's the title of the column? If so, it could be using the actual name instead of the field alias. If it's the actual values, I would follow what Dan C mentioned with field calculations.